# How to connect class?class connected to window

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

Below how to use code to achieve ? class connected to window.

[image]

```
ButtonController *btn=[[ButtonController alloc]init]; 
[btnAbout.cell setTarget:btn];
```

How to achieve mouseEnter events ?

```
#import "ButtonController.h"

@implementation ButtonController

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        NSButton *button = (NSButton *)self;
        NSLog(@"%ldsss",(long)button.tag);
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    // Drawing code here.
}
-(void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent{

    [self mouseEntered:theEvent];
    if (self.tag == 1) {
        NSLog(@"ee");
    }
}
@end
```

=======================================================

=======================================================

=======================================================

```
#import "ButtonController.h"
```

=======================================================

```
ButtonController *btnMax =[[ButtonController alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, 14, 14)];
[btnMax setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"max"]];
[btnMax setAlternateImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"maxDown"]];
[[btnMax cell]setHighlightsBy:NSContentsCellMask];
[btnMax setBordered:NO];
[btnMax setTag:2];
[viewGo addSubview:btnMax];
```

Comment: .xib files are all just xml files so if you right click on the file go to open as and click source code then it'll be somewhere over there. This can't be achieved through you .m and .h files though

Comment: ButtonController *btn=[[ButtonController alloc]init];
    [btnAbout.cell setTarget:btn];  How to achieve mouseEnter events ?